# How to center content in child elements React

Tags: css, reactjs

I have the following code being returned from a component:

```
                <div style={{marginLeft: 330}}>
                    <PostForm />
                    {this.state.posts.map(post => (
                        <Post key={post.id} post={post} />
                    ))}
                </div>
```

How would I use inline styles to make the postform and Post components be centered on the screen on all devices.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'` to the parent component (in this case, the div):

```
    <div style={{
        marginLeft: 330,
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    }}>
        <PostForm />
        {this.state.posts.map(post => (
            <Post key={post.id} post={post} />
        ))}
    </div>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working, all the child elements are centered vertically and next to each other.

Comment: Adding `flexWrap: 'wrap'` on `<div>` will fix the issue with the child elements being next to each other. Since you need a break after every element, then set the `width` of `<PostForm>` and every `<Post>` element to 100%.

Comment: ^

alternatively, you can add this to the div's style: `flexDirection: 'column'`